# Sending data to server from android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android app which collects the configuration of that particular phone and displays it on the phone.
I want that data , i.e , configuration values of a phone, to send to my server. Can anyone help me with the code.

I am getting the codes for sending data from server to the application but not from app to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use websevices, either `SOAP` or `REST`. For `SOAP` you can use `KSOAP2` [KSOAP2 library](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/167-using-ksoap2-for-android-soap-web-service) or for REST [use this link.](http://timewasted.net/?p=127)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Spring for Android](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android) together with [Android Annotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest%20API). e.g

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "http://company.com/ajax/services", converters = { MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.class })
public interface MyRestClient {
    @Get("/events")
    EventList getEvents();
}
```